# Worpress file permisions and ownership after migration

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress on mac and I did a migration to a new macbook, since then I have been having loads of problems with file permision and ownership.

First I was having the:

```
'Upload folder is not writable'
```

I fixed this by adding this entry to the wp-confing.php

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads/');
```

Then when I tried to update a plugin, I got the:

```
'Could not create directory'
```

And I fixed that by changing the owner from `me` to `_www`

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www wp-content
```

And now I can update plugins, but I cannot edit the files with an editor cause `me` does not have access to the files and vscode says:

```
'Failed to save page.php: Insufficient permissions. Select "Retry as Sudo" to retry as superuser.'
```

I have tried:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a `whoami` -t user _www
```

But it still does not let me write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to update plugins, core wordpress and also edit files all in my local version on mac with an nginx server.

```
sudo chown -R _www:staff your-wordpress-folder
sudo chmod -R g+w your-wordpress-folder
```